# Bind method (change_map) with on_press in a pythonic way

Tags: python, button, kivy

i want to bind my method change_map to my button and change screen to "menu" via on_press function.

In a .kv file, it looks like this.

```
        Button:
            id: some_btn
            on_press: root.change_map(); app.root.current = "menu"
```

I need it in a pythonic way but i get an error "AssertionError: None is not callable".

main.py

```
class MapScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MapScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def change_map(self, map_id):
        global MAP_ID
        MAP_ID = map_id

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        file_system = FileSystemLocal()
        maps_folder = file_system .listdir('data/maps') #Gets all file names in the folder
        for i in range(len(maps_folder)-1):
            if "map" in maps_folder[i] and "~" not in maps_folder[i]: 
                map_number = maps_folder[i].replace("map", "").replace(".txt", "") # If it's a map file, get the map number
                map_button = Button(text=map_number,font_name='data/fonts/Square.ttf', size_hint=(0.2, None)) #Button text is the map number
-->             map_button.bind(on_press=self.change_map(map_number)) #When the button is pressed call change_map to change global var
                self.ids.map_choice.add_widget(map_button) #Add the button(s) to the StackLayout in file.kv
```

file.kv

```
<MapScreen>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: app.rgb(52, 152, 219)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    StackLayout:
        id: map_choice
        orientation: 'lr-tb'
        size_hint: .9, .9
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.5}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
map_button.bind(on_press=self.change_map(map_number))
```

This *calls* self.change_map, a function which returns None, and therefore gives your error when you try to call it.

Instead you need to *pass* self.change_map along with your default argument. A good way to do this is using partial:

```
from functools import partial
map_button.bind(on_press=partial(self.change_map, map_number))
```

Comment: Oh ok i understand now, thank you. But how can i do app.root.current = "menu" in a pythonic way if the ScreenManager is defined in the .kv file ?